# Can someone tell if a php script is asking for a cookie?

Tags: php, cookies

If you have a page that requests

```
$cookie = $_COOKIE['mycookie']
```

Can someone tell that you are requesting the cookie? Or does that information get sent in the headers no matter what.

Thanks!

Comment: The title of this question is hilarious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is simply assigning a variable to the value of $_COOKIE['mycookie']. It will attempt even if the cookie is not set. As for getting sent to headers - no, this is doing nothing to the output of the page.

Answer (score 1):

That information is sent in the headers.  If it's not already set in the headers, it will simply return NULL.

So no, simply retrieving a cookie server-side is not detectable from the browser.  If you were to call set_cookie(), on the other hand, that would be a different matter.